# Dismiss UIAlertController with timer

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uialertcontroller

Dismiss a `UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet` after a couple of seconds if the OK button is not tapped.

I tried putting a timer right after presenting the `actionSheet` to call a method to dismiss it but it doesn't close it.

Here is my code:

```
func showActionSheet(){
    
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Some Tile", message: "Some Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.actionSheet)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel, handler: {
        action in
        self.closeSheetView()
    }))

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2 , target: self, selector: #selector(self.closeSheetView), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func closeSheetView(){
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

FYI - the `closeSheetView` method seems to get called but the sheet view doesn't close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i just do it in my projrct without timer i use delay , may be it will work for you ...!

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "alert disappears after 5 seconds", preferredStyle: .alert)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

// here it work for 5 sec
let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
  // your code with delay
  alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: welcome , you an also see / upvote my other answers may it will help you :)